# Can I save a gta5 saved game to a USB stick?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

Can I download a save for Grand theft Auto 5, put it on a usb stick, and use it on my Xbox 360?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you download it and it was created by you, on the same account, then yes. If it was created and owned by somebody else, you will not be able to, as it won't recognise it as your account's save data.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the editor modio or horizon to change the profile and console id's so the save will work.

Need to have a decent knowledge of what to do though.

http://www.game-tuts.com/community/modio.php

https://www.horizonmb.com/

There are many tutorials on how to do this on Youtube.

Comment: These are links to the programs that the user needs to used ASA, what are you talking about?

Comment: Hrm.  Misread the links. My bad.  I still think you should add in instructions on how to use the recommended product to accomplish what it is he's asking for.

Comment: Not within the guidelines of this post, I provided the means to what the user needs to use and indicated that there are many tutorials in which can be of use on Youtube, as it can't be explained via text without writing 400+ words at least, which the /about page of arqade is quite against. Please revise your "-1" as there is no possible further explanation available.

Comment: "There are many tutorials on how to do this on Youtube".  That's why I downvoted.  Telling someone to go somewhere else to figure it out is not helpful.  The vote stands.

Comment: You are telling me to breach what Arqade asks users not to do? You've been here longer than me, way longer, thought a long-term member would know that. Like I said if you could read, seemingly you can't understand, there is no possible text based explanation less than 400 words.

Comment: I'm...sorry?  Nowhere can I find anything that says you are limited to 400 words for...anything.  Anything at all.  Do you have a link or something?  Each answer has an upper limit of 30,000 characters, I believe.  Easily enough to provide at least a basic tutorial on how to use either one of these applications to do what is being asked.

Comment: The about clearly states Don't ask, meaning this question would be under that category "Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14328/discussion-between-frank-and-tweakly)